# jquery replace function works strangely in IE

Tags: jquery, regex, internet-explorer, replace

I have a text box (for price) in which I have to validate that it is numeric data only. Also, I cannot allow zero preceding digits (like 01). So I used the replace method with a regular expression. For replacing letters this was used:

```
$("#txtPrice").keyup(function(){
    var text=$(this).val();
    $(this).val(text.replace(/[^\d\s\.]/,""));
});
```

For replacing a preceding zero, I used

```
$("#txtPrice").keyup(function(){
    var text=$(this).val();
    $(this).val(text.replace(/^0+/, ''));
 });
```

It works fine on firefox, but in IE it behaves strangely.

If I add a new digit in front of the digit, it will add the new digit to the end of the number. For example, if I edit "56" into "156" then the digit 1 is added at the end forming "561". If any digit is attempted to be placed at the front, it is actually added to the end of the textfield. How can solve this behavior?

Comment: this is more likely a problem with the other line, not the regex replacement.  What happens when you put an "alert(text);" in between those 2 lines?

Comment: I believe it would be ideal for you to only have one keyup function bound to a given instance. While possibly not the solution for getting the behavior you are looking for, it is going to make figuring out what is going on easier.

Comment: Hi iijb; if my answer has been a working solution for you, be sure to accept it as the answer or let us know why it doesn't fit your situation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are experiencing is not so much that you are placing 1 at the beginning of your input and IE is slapping it at the end, but that IE is not actually allowing your cursor to move towards the front of the input. It is capturing the arrow / home key operation and triggering the keyup, performing the two regular expressions, and replacing the text.

What you probably will need to do is evaluate what the key was that was detected and only bother with doing something with it if it matches an actual character.

Does something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/tU7vh/2/) address your situation?

```
$("#txtPrice").keyup(function(event) {
    // avoid triggering on control characters; FF ignores but IE will execute and possibly confuse
    if (event.which > 40) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(text.replace(/^0+/, ''));
        $(this).val(text.replace(/[^\d\s\.]/,""));
    }
});
```

You'll probably have to make some exceptions to `event.which > 40` and I'm not entirely sure how you would allow the user's cursor to stay where they just pressed a key, but I think this might be a sufficient solution for you.

**Edit**: I combined the regex into one; see updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tU7vh/4/).

```
$(this).val(text.replace(/(^0+|[^\d\s\.])/, ""));
```

**Edit**: If you want to have the cursor 'jump around' as little as possible, then you could optionally replace the illegal text when you've already verified that that text matches. [Here is a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/tU7vh/6/).

```
if ($(this).val().match(/(^0+|[^\d\s\.])/)) {
    $(this).val(text.replace(/(^0+|[^\d\s\.])/, ""));
}
```

You could also extrapolate the Regular Expression into a variable as I have done in the fiddle.

Comment: Hi, it solved my problem. But now after insertion the cursor goes at the rear.

Comment: Great @iijb; you should probably accept this as the answer to your original problem and then open a new problem ticket after you have explored different options. [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tU7vh/5/) where the cursor will only get moved if they have done something 'illegal'.